# Ambiguity in output of two different types after modification of its value ?

Tags: c#, .net

I am having two variables of type `string` and `SelectListItem` and trying to use them in my code where i found something weird and looking for a reason .

**Scenario 1:**

```
public class Test1
 {
       string x=""

       void Assign(string x)
        {
        x="I am modified value";
        }

        public void myMethod()
        {     
            Assign(x); 

            console.WriteLine(x) // output : ""
        }

  }
```

**Scenario 2 :**

```
public class Test2
 {
       void Assign(SelectListItem x)
        {
        x.Text="Modified Text";
        x.Value="Modified Value";
        }

        public void myMethod()
        {     
            var x = new SelectListItem()
            x.Text="present Text";
            x.Value="present Value";
            Assign(x); 

            console.WriteLine(x) // output : Text:"Modified Text" & Value:"Modified Value"
        }

  }
```

You can see in `scenario1` my output is `""` even tough i assign `x="I am modified value"` inside a function before printing the o/p but where as in `scenario2` i get output of modified value `Text:"Modified Text" & Value:"Modified Value"` .

I really cant find a reason here only i can think is in `scenario2` we are passing instance . so , when we modify automatically the change gets effected but i'm not sure is it really reason behind that one and no clue about `scenario1`

Comment: Read about variable scope.

Comment: In scenario1 inside the `Assign` method write, `this.x="I am modified value";`. You'll get your output. The main issue is the scope of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference types are also passed by value. When you pass a reference type variable it's reference value is copied into the parameter. Assigning a new reference will just create a new instance and copy the new reference value into the variable.So, it won't affect the variable you passed.On the other hand you are modifying the properties of `SelectListItem`. It's not the same as assigning a new reference, in that case since both parameter and the variable refers to the same location, you are modifying the same object.

There is a name collision between your parameter and class field. If you wanna modify the class field use `this.x = x`. If that's not the case you can use `ref` modifier:

```
void Assign(ref string x)
{
   x="I am modified value";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first you pass `string`. Here you immediately reassign the reference itself, causing a disconnection with the variable that passed it in. If you would have used the `ref` modifier, the re-assignment would be propagated to the passed in argument.

In the latter you pass an object and change that object's properties inside the method. However you are still doing these operations on the same object as the one that's passed in: both references point to the same object. That's why these changes are visible in both contexts.

Comment: String is tricky, even if is a reference type has different behaviours if compared or passed as parameter or assigned directly. +1